# htaccess | How to redirect using RewriteRule ? Simple

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have this URL pointing my web site:

```
http://www.mysite.ext/.htaccess.aspx-->/
```

and I like to redirected to

```
http://www.mysite.ext/
```

but I can't.

In my .htaccess file I have enter this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.htaccess(.+))/?$  http://www.mysite.ext/?        [R=301,L]
```

but doesn't work

also I have try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(\.htaccess\.aspx(.*))/?$  http://www.mysite.ext/?        [R=301,L]
```

but still no luck. I don't know if that helps, but the site is based on PHP.

Any idea please ?

Is it realy so hard ?

Can somebody to help me please ?

Comment: I notice you have a double space in your rewriterules

Comment: Where ? Between the /?$ and the http://www.mysite.ext/? ?

Comment: why do you have parens in your rules if you're not using anything you capture? why redirect to a url that ends with a `?`?

Comment: @sgroves Ending a rewritten url with a ? clears the query string

Comment: @Sumurai8 wouldn't redirecting to just `http://www.mysite.ext/` do the same thing?

Comment: Did you turn the rewriteengine on?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes the rewrite engine is on. This is migration from another web site that hacked and the hacked web site, it had a tone of 404 URLs. Among them 404 generated URLs is the above one. While the other URL's are totaly rewrited, the one above it can't. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are you getting requests for `/.htaccess.aspx` and why you want to redirect them.

However keep in mind that Apache configs usually block access to `.htaccess` using directive like below:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

That throws 403 (Forbidden) error for any request that starts with `/.ht`.

**Workaround:**

Have a custom handler for 403:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errorPage403.php
```

and have this redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\.htaccess\.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]
```